# ReSwift middleware to load initial state

Tags: swift, redux, swift4, reswift

How do I load the initial app state from the database using ReSwift?

I'm thinking something like a middleware for when the app state is first being initialized, i.e., the first time the reducers are called.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is the Middleware.

Mean this, you can make an `Action` with name `InitializeApp` for example.
Create too a `Middleware` like `DataBaseMiddleware`.

Inside your `Middleware` you can create a conditional to check if `action` is `InitializeApp`, and get the data from `DataBase` after load completed you can `dispatch` actions to update your `States`.

Think inside your middleware you can dispatch UpdateUserInfo(name, age), UpdatePreferences..

I hope I was helpful.